# Present simple or present continuous in this case

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous

Is present simple or present continuous correct in this case?

> I **eagerly wait/am eagerly waiting** for a new episode of "Dynamite" on the radio.

I think the first one is a better solution  because it is a habit to listen  to this radio show: it is a kind of routine.

Comment: _I eagerly wait_ describes your routine as the time for each episode approaches. _I am eagerly waiting_ describes your state of mind now, if the next one will be broadcast soon.

Comment: As normal, present simple describes a routine, and present continuous describes something happening now. Whichever the case is will determine which form is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The programme has been on air for a decade. You are an avid fan of it. You watched every single episode of it, and **you eagerly wait** for a new one. It has somewhat become a routine of yours.

Your friend said he was on the "Dynamite" show. You've never heard of it, but you love your friend and **you are eagerly waiting** for that episode to come out.

In either case, however, you can use the present continuous to convey your **current** **state** of anticipation.